# Can't get Twitter Bootstrap affix to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to basically copy the Bootstrap homepage and I'm stuck on how they got the sidebar to work.

It seems they use the [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) plugin. I created the CSS as advised and while it seems to work when I have my browser maximised, but not when it's a small phone-sized window.

Instead of the sidebar and content following after each other, they overlap.

http://bootply.com/95495
Relevant code starts on line 30ish.

Note: the Welcome seems to be buggy too, but I only get that on Bootply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for the bootstrap 3 Grid

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

But here you have the solution

You need to set the grid for small devices like this:

class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/674/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0" class="hidden-print" role="complementary">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#1.0">1.0</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li>
                <a href="#1.1">1.1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#2.0">2.0</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li>
                <a href="#2.1">2.1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9  col-xs-12">
      <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id diam nec felis bibendum rutrum a et lectus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin vitae mollis nisi. Donec vel eleifend tortor. Sed quis pharetra lectus. Vestibulum lacus lacus, laoreet vel justo nec, blandit fringilla dui. Vestibulum bibendum euismod luctus. Cras non mauris ultrices, pharetra orci in, tempor turpis. Donec ut purus tristique, lacinia felis faucibus, sollicitudin erat. Integer a eros vel nisl rutrum dapibus. Integer nulla felis, mattis quis luctus sed, faucibus non eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sed euismod quam. Fusce velit ipsum, rhoncus venenatis luctus vitae, vestibulum eget dui. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris et ipsum nisl.
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You example still has the two columns overlapping. I also thought that by specifying `col-md-3` it would implicitly use `col-xs-1` when the screen gets to that size.

Comment: Try it again, Its working properly, the colums overlap when the sreen size is les than 200px , no device has this width

Comment: Shouldn't they stack vertically? They start to overlap with a width of about 1000px.

Comment: Check the fiddle now, I can´t reproduce the overlaping but when the screen get smaller than 768 you need to remove the position fixed to the nav

Comment: Perfect! I guess I just need to specify for each screen size (xs, sm, md) then.